# Define a appropriate entity to store number intervals

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai

I am wondering what is the ideal way to define entities of different kinds with interval value. e.g. with maximum and minimum number.

I tried to define a `number-interval`entity with min and max values. Then defined a `price-range` composite entity with `@number-interval` + `@sys.currency-name`. (See attached images)

There are two issues with this. First, there are too many ways for user to say it. For instance, it can recognize `User says: above 12 USD` but can not recognize `User says: more than 12 USD`

Is there any better way to define it that uses system entities?

For example, let's say we want to collect two different values from user.

The other problem is, let's say we want to collect two different kind values from user. How to distinguish the correct entity (price_range vs. size_range)?

Example:

1. `user says: 1200 to 1500` in **get_price** action. should return `@price-range`
2. `user says: 9-10` in **get_size** action. should return `@size-range`

**P.S.**
Entities:

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: Your question may be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568187/best-way-to-handle-ranges-in-api-ai. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no range/interval system entity (all Dialogflow system entities can be found [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities))

To answer the second part of your question: Get 2 different kinds of values from the user. You can use contexts to narrow down the options (see [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts))

- Question: "What is the price?" (output context: **price**)
- Answer: "10-50" (context: **price**)
- Intent get_price (input context: **price**) **<- this will trigger**
- Intent get_size (input context: size) <- this will never trigger

Only an intent with the same context can trigger. If an intent doesn't have an input context it can always trigger (for example a "help" intent without a context).