# Dialogflow: Guide user to a specific flow depending on user's age

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying out some things with Google Dialogflow. The thing I am basically trying to do is ask the user's age. Based on the age, say greater than 50 OR smaller than 50, I want the user to be guided to a specific question for one of the two age groups.

I was looking on the internet for a hint or suggestion, but I can't find examples other than "Yes","No" type of answers which then guide the user to a specific flow.

I basically need the user to say an age, which can be between 1-50 years, and 50-100 years, and any number belonging to any of the two groups should prompt the user to a specific follow-up question for that age group.

Does any one have a tip? Is this even possible in the generic Google Dialogflow? Or would I need to use a webhook/fullfilment for this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use fulfillment for this sort of thing. Dialogflow Intents are good at capturing *what* the user has said, and possibly including this as a parameter, but webhooks are best for applying logic and determining output and what context further answers should be considered in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Do you have any suggestion how to set this up or do you know of an example? I'm a bit lost where to start with this specific type of question, which is essentially a range of numbers between 0-50 and 50-100. How could I set this up with fulfillment?

Comment: You'd want to ask for the user's age, then capture that as a number entity in a new intent. The response to this intent would be your fulfillment.

Comment: Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579568/6763544) for help.